# How to prevent cross-site websocket hijacking?

Tags: javascript, http, websocket, same-origin-policy

I am writing a SaaS web application, in which data is served to the client via websockets. I have implemented authentication via user access token on connection. I need to prevent websocket connection from a different site as well as from curl requests.

Site origin policy and cross origin resource sharing (CORS) are ineffective for websockets, so when upgrading the http connection to websocket, verifying the origin header would prevent access from another website, since Origin header is verified by browser.

The issue here is that only browser originated requests mandate authentic origin. Origins can be spoofed via curl requests outside of a browser. How then could I prevent a user connecting to the websocket using their authentication token and spoofing the origin?

Comment: You can't.  If you want to allow users to connect from a certain origin but only the client knows what origin its on, you have to trust the client to tell you what the origin is.

Answer (score 2):

> verifying the origin header would prevent access from another website, since Origin header is verified by browser.

This is the answer to your question in the title—verifying the HTTP Origin header on the server side will prevent hijacking, since the browser is going to send the correct origin.

It is not clear why you are concerned about the ability for a user to connect outside of the browser. Like CSRF, cross-site websocket hijacking is effectively an attack against the user's browser and its naive willingness to send credentials cross-site in certain scenarios, and is not an attack against the server itself. As such, the concept of an origin header for security purposes is not really relevant outside the browser context.

With a website, you do not really control anything about the client. Even if a user is really on your site in the browser with the correct origin, they could run JavaScript to send arbitrary WebSocket messages anyway. If you are still worried about the user's ability to do this, then it may be wise to spend some time auditing the logic and validation on the server side to ensure the application behaves correctly regardless of what the user throws at it.